How to debug the Kryo fallback in Flink?
I wonder which is the simplest way of troubleshooting/debugging what causes
the Kryo fallback.
Detecting it is just a matter of adding this line to your job:
env.getConfig().disableGenericTypes();

or in more recent versions:
pipeline.generic-types: false

But once you detect the issue, what is the simplest way to debug it?
You can of course add a breakpoint within:
org.apache.flink.api.java.typeutils.TypeExtractor@analyzePojo

but ideally there should be a simpler way to show all the problems
encountered to the user without having to get that deep into the code.
